# Condition line feed

Tags: tabularx

I set a condition to describe a formula but I am not able to make a line feed. How can I change my condition that this is possible.

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
%____________________________________________________________________________________________________________
\newenvironment{conditions}
  {\par\vspace{\abovedisplayskip}\noindent\begin{tabular}{>{$}l<{$} @{${}={}$} l}}
  {\end{tabular}\par\vspace{\belowdisplayskip}}
%____________________________________________________________________________________________________________
\begin{document}
\begin{conditions}
    \mu_{j}^{(i)} \mathrm{d}N_{j}^{(i)} &  infinitesimal change in entropy in amount of substance from each component (i = component \&  j = phase) 
\end{conditions}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

With the help  of `tabularx` that you already loaded:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
%____________________________________________________________________________________________________________
\newenvironment{conditions}
  {\par\vspace{\abovedisplayskip}\noindent\tabularx{\textwidth}{>{$}l<{$} @{${}={}$} X}}
  {\endtabularx\par\vspace{\belowdisplayskip}}
%____________________________________________________________________________________________________________
\begin{document}
\begin{conditions}
    \mu_{j}^{(i)} \mathrm{d}N_{j}^{(i)} &  infinitesimal change in entropy in amount of substance from each component (i = component \&  j = phase) 
\end{conditions}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

A variant of leandriis's answer, where `displaymath` is used instead of manual spacing.

I also add a variant for usage inside `gather`, so the description can be in the same display as the equation.

The optional argument uses a fraction of the available width (default 0.8), that can be modified with `\begin{conditions}[0.9]` (or whatever you see fit).

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{xparse}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for mock text

\NewDocumentEnvironment{conditions}{O{0.8}b}
 {%
  \[\begin{tabularx}{#1\displaywidth}{@{}>{$\displaystyle}r<{={}$}@{}X@{}}
  #2
  \end{tabularx}\]%
 }
 {}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{conditions*}{O{0.8}}
 {
  \nonumber\tabularx{#1\displaywidth}{@{}>{$\displaystyle}r<{={}$}@{}X@{}}
 }
 {
  \endtabularx
 }

\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-4]
\begin{conditions}
\mu_{j}^{(i)} \diff N_{j}^{(i)} &
  infinitesimal change in entropy in amount of  substance from 
  each component ($i=\text{component}$ and  $j=\text{phase}$)
\\
x & something else
\end{conditions}
\lipsum[1][1-4]
\begin{gather}
\int\mu_{j}^{(i)} \diff N_{j}^{(i)}=x \\
\begin{conditions*}
\mu_{j}^{(i)} \diff N_{j}^{(i)} &
  infinitesimal change in entropy in amount of  substance from 
  each component ($i=\text{component}$ and  $j=\text{phase}$)
\\
x & something else
\end{conditions*}
\end{gather}
\lipsum[1][1-4]

\end{document}
```

[image]